# Non-macro versions of clojure "and" and "or"

Tags: clojure

Are there non-macro versions of [`and`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/and) and [`or`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/or) in Clojure?

*Update:  In this case I don't care about the short circuiting.*

Comment: Probably not. If you implement 'and' and 'or' as functions, all the arguments would get evaluated, which is not what you want in a typical 'and' or 'or' implementation. For example, if the first argument in an 'and' expression is false, you don't have to evaluate the rest of the arguments.

Comment: Why do you want a non-macro version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [`or`](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/or)

The function [`some`](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some) "Returns the first logical true value of (pred x) for any x in coll, else nil."

So you could use `(some identity coll)` for `or`.  Note that its behaviour will differ from `or` when the last value is `false`: it will return `nil` where `or` would return `false`.

#### [`and`](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/and)

If you don't need to know the value of the last form in the `coll` vector, you can use `(every? identity coll)` for `and`.  This will differ from the behaviour of the `and` macro in that it returns `true` if all of its arguments are truthy.  See larsmans' answer if you need the result of the last form.

Comment: `every?` seems to be the counterpart of `and`.

Comment: @larsmans: It's close, but it returns `true` rather than the last-tested value.  So you'd have to do something like `(defn land [coll] (if (every? coll) (last coll)))`.  Your answer is probably more efficient for a lot of tests because it avoids iterating through the collection twice.

Comment: ok, but that's a two-pass version. It would be `(every? identity coll)`, btw.

Comment: Aha, yes - `every?` and `some` are what I need.
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/every_q
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some

Answer (score 5):

Let `land` stand for "logical and", then they're trivial to define:

```
(defn land
  ([] true)
  ([x & xs] (and x (apply land xs))))
```

Or, slightly closer to the standard `and` behavior:

```
(defn land
  ([] true)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & xs] (and x (apply land xs))))
```

And similarly for `or`.

Comment: What about `(and x (apply land xs))` instead of using `if`?

Comment: @Rafał: yes, that's even better. Updated.

Comment: Maybe even `(and (apply land xs) x)` to boost the evil even more by forcing lazy seqs to evaluate :)

Comment: @RafałDowgird the version with `if` runs 40% faster!

Answer (score 3):

This actually [came up as a topic](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure-dev/browse_thread/thread/899349c6a9b526e0) on clojure-dev recently.  Rich Hickey ultimately concluded they should be added to core for 1.3 as every-pred and any-pred (logged as [CLJ-729](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-729)).  I think further discussions there have led them to now be called every-pred (the and variant) and some-fn (the or variant).  The final version was just recently [committed](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/8c783f1c1a6fb0cf9c50e4737596e92bceb8012b) to master.

Comment: I don't think that `every-pred` and `some-fn` are what the question is about. As far as I understand they evaluate every element of a collection against every predicate in a set (sort of a carthesian product) and check whether all/any of the predicate-argument pairs evaluate to true. Interesting news anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean functions: no, and they cannot be.  The reason is that function forms always evaluate all their arguments before applying the function to their value.  You do not want that here.

Comment: Ok, so in this case I don't care about the short-circuit behaviour as my arguments will have no side effects.  Also, some amount of short-circuiting may still be possible if the arguments are a lazy sequence.

Comment: @pauldoo: It's almost never about side effects. Consider `(and (seq coll) (< (first coll) 5))`. The second expression is only valid when the first evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

Most cases where you want this there is a more idiomatic way to do it, but just an exercise, it is possible to defer evaluation by thunking. Thunk your expressions and give them to logical operators that evaluate the the thunk when needed, using the standard and/or:

```
(defn &&* [& fns]
  (cond (= 1 (count fns)) ((first fns))
        :otherwise
        (and ((first fns)) (apply &&* (next fns)))))

(defn ||* [& fns]
  (cond (= 1 (count fns)) ((first fns))
        :otherwise
        (or ((first fns)) (apply ||* (next fns)))))

Example use:

(map 
  (partial apply &&*) 
    (map (partial map constantly) ;; thunk all of these values 
      [["yes" "no"] 
       [false true]
       [true "something"] 
       [true "something" "false"]]))

("no" false "something" "false")
```

Another Example:

```
(defmacro thunks
  "convert expressions into thunks to prevent advance evaluation"
  [& exprs]
  (let [fns# (map (fn [e] `(fn [] ~e)) exprs)]
    (cons 'vector fns#)))

(apply ||* (thunks (+ 1 2) false (* 1 5)))
3
(apply &&* (thunks (+ 1 2) false (* 1 5)))
false
(apply &&* (thunks (+ 1 2) (* 1 5)))
5
```